# Using Fubini's Theorem in Stochastic Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, isometry

In basic calculus: 'Fubini's theorem' allows us to switch order of integration in double integrals without changing the bounds provided we are integrating over a rectangle. From [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/fubini-s-theorem-and-evaluating-double-integrals-over-rectan):

[image]

If the area is not a rectangle, we will very likely have to change the bounds.

---

In stochastic calculus:

Let $T > 0$. Given a stochastic process $\{ X_t \}_{t \in [0,T]}$ on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$, we can say by ['Fubini's theorem'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) that

$$\mathbb{E} [\int_0^T X_t^2 dt] = \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[X_t^2] dt$$

or, if I'm not mistaken

$$\int_{\Omega} \int_0^T X_t^2 dt d\mathbb{P} = \int_0^T \int_{\Omega} X_t^2 d\mathbb{P} dt$$

The left hand side of the first equation comes from here: [Itô isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), so all the assumptions apply.

**Question**: Why is it that the bounds do not change?

Well obviously we can just look at the [link earlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions), but how can this be put in terms of 'Fubini's theorem' in basic calculus? I'm looking for an explanation for a beginning stochastic calculus student who knows only some basics of measure theory. As far as a beginning stochastic Calculus student knows, 'Fubini's theorem' is that proposition from basic Calculus which is for Riemann integrals and assumes rectangular area of integration. So how is that applicable here? Is such an area $\Omega \times [0, T]$ rectangular?

Comment: Fubini's theorem, in the version you state it (!), is not applicable here since the measure $\mathbb{P}$ is, obviously, not the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @saz you mean we can switch if it is lebesgue measure but we might not be able to if it is not lebesgue measure?

Comment: That's not what I said. We *can* switch the integrals, but we cannot use the theorem mentioned in your question to prove it.

Comment: @saz [?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/172387/44339)

Comment: yes, but the "Fubini thm" they mention there, is not the same one you cite in your question. You state Fubini's theorem only for the Lebesgue measure and that's not good enough for this application. What we need is Fubini's theorem for arbitrary ($\sigma$-finite) measures, i.e. $$\int \int f(x,y) \, \mu(dx) \, \nu(dy) = \int \int f(x,y) \, \nu(dy) \, \mu(dx) = \iint f(x,y) \, d(\mu \otimes \nu)(x,y).$$

Comment: @saz Perhaps I linked wrong. I was supposed to link to '  Tonelli's theorem for non-negative functions', which was linked to in the other post? Sorry for confusion if any. The Fubini's Thm in the picture is different from the latter link on Fubini. My question is about looking at the Fubini's for arbitrary sigma-finite measures in terms of the Fubini's in basic calculus, particularly for the bounds. My question is why the bounds of the integral do not change in the stochastic calculus equation, like maybe it has something to do with the area being rectangular or something. Like still

Comment: @saz 0 to T and over the whole Omega even after switching the order of integration? From basic calculus I remember that switching the order of integration usually means changing the bounds of integration. No need to change the bounds if the area is rectangular

Comment: I see. We agree, I hope, that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$$ (assuming that Fubini is applicable), i.e. if we integrate over the whole space, then we don't have to change the bounds of integration. The same holds true for general measure spaces. In your setting, $$\int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t,\omega) \, dt \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\Omega} f(t,\omega) \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \, dt.$$ Now apply this identity to $$f(t,\omega) := X_t^2(\omega) 1_{[0,T]}(t).$$

Comment: @saz Thanks! Is that a continuous function though? Anywayz post as answer?

Comment: Wait I think I got it. It's continuous but might not be differentiable?

Comment: $t \mapsto X_t^2(\omega)$ is continuous, but $f$ is not continuous (it has a jump at $t=T$). However, $f$ is measurable and that's enough.

Comment: @saz The original Fubini's thm seems to require f to be continuous. So I guess the stocal Fubini's thm changes that assumption to measurable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (In general, we don't even know what "continuity" means on a measure space... for example if $X$ is a random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, then it does, in general, not make sense to speak about continuity of $\omega \mapsto X(\omega)$.)

Comment: Thanks @saz Seems to make sense. Shame you did not post as answer

Comment: @saz Thanks for the +15 I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on saz' comments:

'if we integrate over the whole space, then we don't have to change the bounds of integration'

$$\int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) dx dy = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) dy dx$$

for applicable f. Also,

$$\int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb R} f(t,\omega) dt d\mathbb P = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\Omega} f(\omega,t) d\mathbb P dt$$

for applicable f. Now apply: $$f(t, \omega) := X_t^2(\omega)1_{[0,T]}(t)$$

A notable difference b/w the 2 Fubini's Thms is that in basic calculus, f is required to be continuous. In stochastic calculus, $f$ is not required to be continuous, but $f$ is required to be measurable.