# Prove $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(z) dz = f(x)$

Tags: limits, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

From 2.27 [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e67a/551a4e7d471269365e3f9780ba5a171863bc.pdf)

> Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1] \to \mathbb R$.
>
> $$\lambda\left(\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(z) dz = f(x)\right) = 1$$

The proof might actually involve things beyond my level but here's my attempt anyway:

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(z) dz$$

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2r} [\int_{0}^{x+r} f(z) dz - \int_{0}^{x-r} f(z) dz]$$

$$\stackrel{LHR}{=} \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2} [f(x+r) - f(x-r)(-1)]$$

$$\stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{2} [f(x+0) + f(x-0)] \tag{*}$$

$$= f(x)$$

$(*)$ Guess based on [Using Fubini's Theorem in Stochastic Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482207/using-fubinis-theorem-in-stochastic-calculus), $f$ is not continuous, but the justification is that $f$ is measurable. $(*)$ does not work for finitely many points and hence the $\lambda$-almost everywhere.

If it's completely wrong to approach this in a Riemann/basic calculus/non-measure theory way, which parts and why please?

Comment: This is a non-trivial result in measure theory called the Lebesgue Theorem. There is a lot of difference between the case where $f$ is continuous and the one where $f$ is just integrable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)? If so, thanks! You can post your comment as answer. That's a relief to know. I thought my not knowing was indicative of poor background. I had only one advanced real analysis class. I believe the first topic for a would be succeeding class in my university would be differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-trivial result in measure theory called Lebesgue' Theorem. There is a lot of difference between the case where f is continuous and the one where f is only integrable.

Comment: Again, thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 1):

As Kavi Rama Murthy said, this is a nontrivial theorem in measure theory called the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. The statement of the theorem is as follows:

If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$  is integrable, then $\frac{1}{|B(x, r)|}\int_{B(x,  r)}f(y)\,d y \to f(x)$ as $r \to 0$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Everything here is with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $|B(x,  r)|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of the ball at $x$ of radius $r$. Proving this for a general integrable function $f$ requires more sophisticated techniques than for a continuous function $f$.

The quantity $\frac{1}{|B(x,r )|}\int_{B(x,r )}f(y)\,d y$ is the average  of $f$  over the ball $B(x, r)$. What this theorem is saying is that as we take smaller and smaller balls centered at a point $x$, the average of $f$ on these balls approaches the value of $f$ at the center of these balls. For continuous $f$, this is relatively intuitive. In full generality, the theorem says that this holds at "most"  points.

Comment: Thanks Chris. The last paragraph's intuition is pretty much the same as fundamental theorem of basic calculus except for continuity right?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. A slight difference is that the FTC states $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{r}\int_x^{x + r}f(y)\, dy = f(x)$, rather than the $2r$ and $\int_{x -  r}^{x + r}$ that appears in this "version."